# Android: How do I get the file date from a URL for an image I want to download?

Tags: android, url, date

I want to query the server to see if the date is different than the one I have on the phone
that I previously downloaded. I want to keep from un-necessarily downloading the image again if I already have it.  Looking for a way to get remote URL file date AND time without downloading the image again. Code Below that fetches all.

```
       File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   URL u = new URL(url);
   HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
   c.setRequestMethod("GET");
   c.setDoOutput(true);
   c.connect();
   InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
   Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(in, "src name");
   printi("Content length",c.getContentLength());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   URL u = new URL(url);
   HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
   c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

   c.connect();
   InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
   long dt=c.getLastModified();  //File Modified Date!!!
   printtime("File Time ",dt);
   c.disconnect();       //close connection  ????
```